# How to run set of terminal commands in a file one by one?

Tags: bash, shell, command

I was working on a Django project and each time I open the project, I have to run these three commands one by one.

`source virtualenv/bin/activate` (to activate virtual environment)

`cd myproject` (to enter project folder)

`python3 manage.py runserver` (to run the server)

Is there a way I can write these three commands in a text file (or some other file) so that a single command will run these three commands one by one?

Before running those three commands, terminal looks like this:[image: Image-1]

After running those three commands, the terminal should look like this: [image: Image-2]

Comment: You mean like a shell script?

Comment: Yes, if it is possible.

Comment: Now that you know what to look for you should have no trouble finding it.

Comment: Actually running shell script is not showing any changes in terminal. I want it to activate virtual environment and run server. But it is not happening.Or I don't know whether I've written the correct script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
In file `runscript.sh`,

```
#!/bin/bash
source virtualenv/bin/activate
cd myproject
python3 manage.py runserver
```

Then run command: `. runscript.sh` instead of `./runscript.sh`

Comment: What is the difference between ./runscript.sh and . runscript.sh which makes the latter to work as expected by OP

Answer (score 0):

Save following content to a file `runserver.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
source virtualenv/bin/activate && cd myproject && python3 manage.py runserver
```

and

```
chmod 744 runserver.sh
```

And you can just run `./runserver.sh`

`&&` will ensure previous command was successful before running next command. If any command fails to run, it will abort rest.

Comment: This is not working.The virtual environment is not activated and it hasn't entered the folder 'myproject'. But it is just running server.